# Increment integer model variable using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Just starting to use rails and I hit a snag that I can't seem to find an accurate answer to for my specific case.

I wish to increment the variable 'votes' in my 'Font' model through ajax. I currently have Javascript that triggers this through a click action on a div

The nearest example I've found to my problem is a Favourite button i.e. twitter. However, most 'Favourite button' functionality uses a separate Favourite data model; I only wish to increment the variable therefore I see little point in designing a whole new data model for this.

The Javascript on index.html.erb

```
$("#heading_vote").click(function(){
  var fontid='<%= h @font_1.id %>'
  $(".text").html(fontid);
  $.ajax({type: "GET", url: 'fonts/'+fontid+'/vote', success: function(){
      $(".text").html('voted');
    }
  });
});
```

rake routes

```
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
     root GET  /                         home#index
    fonts GET  /fonts(.:format)          fonts#index
         POST  /fonts(.:format)          fonts#create
 new_font GET  /fonts/new(.:format)      fonts#new
edit_font GET  /fonts/:id/edit(.:format) fonts#edit
     font GET  /fonts/:id(.:format)      fonts#show
        PATCH  /fonts/:id(.:format)      fonts#update
          PUT  /fonts/:id(.:format)      fonts#update
       DELETE  /fonts/:id(.:format)      fonts#destroy
         POST  /fonts/:id/vote(.:format) fonts#vote
```

font.rb model (sets the 'votes' variable to 0 as default when initialised)

```
class Font < ActiveRecord::Base  
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates :linktitle, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates :link, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }

  #set defauls value for votes variable
  before_save :default_values
  def default_values
    self.votes ||= '0'
  end
end
```

The action inside font_controller.rb that increments the 'votes' variable by one:

```
def vote
  @font = Font.find(params[:id])

  @font.update_attribute("votes",votes+1)    

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

my routes.rb file (I think this is where the problem is - am I linking correctly to the vote action in the Font controller?):

```
app::Application.routes.draw do

  root to: "home#index" 

  resources :fonts

  post '/fonts/:id/vote' => 'fonts#vote'
```

Any help, or advice on debugging, would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They way I would do:

I'd the remove js code then:

in **routes** file:

```
post '/fonts/:id/vote' => 'fonts#vote', as: :vote
```

in **view** template:

```
<%= link_to 'Vote', vote_path(@font), remote: true %>
```

in **app/views/fonts/vote.js.erb**

```
alert('Vote saved!');
```

you might want to write more js things into js.erb file to make it look more user friendly, but as a demo an alert will be fine.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; thanks a lot for your help so far. I implemented what you've shown, deleting the Javascript and replacing with a `link_to` however it still doesn't increment the _vote_ variable; in fact the alert in **vote.js.erb** doesn't even show.. any ideas? The `link_to` shows as the following in html `<a data-remote="true" href="/fonts/14/vote">Vote</a>`

Comment: The link looks good, post the logs of the server when running this action.. Also in controler try `@font.increment!(:votes)` instead of `update_attributes`

Comment: Got it! Turns out I had `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` in my layout, which was searching for a file that didn't exist, and I needed `protect_from_forgery except: :index` in my fonts controller to prevent authenticity issues. Thanks a lot for your help, and sorry for the late replies!